# Cant able to reuse custom cells in table view

Tags: iphone, ios

I created a custom cell which contains a label and textfield.I am using this custom cell in table view. When i enter the data in text field  and when i scroll the view my data is getting replaced.For every scroll it getting replaced/erased.Any one tell me where i am doing mistake.
My custom cell code goes here.Thanks!

```
-(UITableViewCell *)returnCellForEach:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellToAddDetails" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;
//        customCell = nil;
        customLabel = (UILabel *)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(UITextField *)dataField
{
    UITextField *textField = customField;

    return textField;
}
```

Comment: What is `returnCellForEach:` and where are you calling it from?

Comment: @jrturton: This is my custom method.i created it for custom cells.

Comment: _And where are you calling it from_? Where is your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the data input by user somewhere related to particular indexpath and When you scroll through the cells you will first need to check if there is any dataObject corresponding to that indexpath and accordingly set the data. You can use a dictionary to store your data corresponding to particular cell. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Actually i am doing a Birthday Remainder Application in which it works with database.I am storing all this textfield values in database. Again if i use dictionary it will create any problem in saving data in database?

Comment: NO issues, You can safely use database but while you are working with tableview and you scroll through the tablecells you can use dictionary to temporary save data ..later you can save this data into database and accordingly fetch as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the method names that you are using, in my case I needed to create a custom Table view Cell Class outside the tableview class,

the class is called QRTYPECELL and following are the relevant codes:

```
@implementation QRTypeCell
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize labelview;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    imageView = nil;
    labelview= nil;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    self.labelview = label;
    [self.contentView addSubview:label];


}
return self;}
```

And then in the TableView Class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

QRTypeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[QRTypeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}
    CurrentQRCode = (QRCode *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *icon = CurrentQRCode.parsed_icon;
    NSString *string = CurrentQRCode.parsed_string;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;    
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:icon ofType:@"png"]; 
    UIImage *image_file = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: :Please answer my question.You answer wont fit for my question.You are giving answer for table view.And my part of question is different.Any way thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

in IB you see a Identifier field place any value in that and use that value as a reuse Identifier.
i think this will helps you.

Comment: :I did that Before. And there is no change .

Comment: did you placed same name @"Identifier" in both

Comment: Both means? I placed it only in the custom cell IB .Only in custom cells i am reusing it right.Did i need to use still any where else?

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it did you create class for customCell and replace this line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
```

with

```
CustomCell *customCell=(CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```